# siunitx: enclose all units in brackets

Tags: siunitx

when I use the command

```
\SI{1}{\kilo\gram}
```

I'd like it to output

> 1 [kg]

Is there a setting so that SIUnitx automatically does this for all units in a document?

Comment: **DON'T DO THAT** There's a reason why `siunitx` doesn't do that by default:  it's wrong. Please, see [this post of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28918/20058) about the usage of brackets in units and the [SI brochure](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf) from p. 147 on.

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano I completely agree though I have provided a technical solution to the question of the OP in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such option. You could redefine the `\SI` command. Here is a very basic approach which could be improved from the technical point of view in many ways.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand{\SI}[3][]{\mbox{$\num[#1]{#2}\,\left[\si{#3}\right]$}}

\begin{document}

\SI{1}{\kilo\gram}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: Output of the MWE]

*Edit:* Please note, however, the valid comment by [Massimo Ortolano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/50910/massimo-ortolano) below the question.