# Equations with parts of different size

Tags: equations, parts, size

I want to put the physical dimensions (units) in the equations, but I want them to have a different color and a different size from those of the equations. In order to achieve this, I tried to define a command that performs that. And it does, but then, everything is written after the command is also reduced in size. The command is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\unidm}[1]{\scriptstyle\textcolor{red}{$\left(\right.$#1$\left.\right)$}}
```

And this is how it is used:

```
\begin{equation}
\vec{x}(t) = \left[ \frac{125}{2}\unidm{m} + 25(t - 5\unidm{s})\unidm{m$cdot$s$^{-1}$} - \frac{5}{2}(t - 5\unidm{m})^2\unidm{m$\cdot$s$^{-2}$}\right]\hat{i}, ~~&\text{si } t\in[5,10]\unidm{s}
\end{equation}
```

And this is its outcome:

[image: Outcome of the \unidm{} command]

Only the fraction previous to the first command use (125/2) stays with normal size.

The idea is that only the physical dimensions in the equations have a smaller size.

Any idea of why the command changes the size of everything coming up after their use and of how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. First note that English is the standard language used here. For typesetting dimensions I recommend the [`siunitx`](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) package. The problem with your command is that `\scriptsize` is escaping the command. If you wrap the entire last argument of your `\newcommand` in curly braces, `{` and `}`, this should fix your problem.

Comment: Excellent!! The curly braces effectively fix the problem! I must say that I started to use LaTeX less than three months ago, really starting from nothing, so I have had this kind of problems innumerable times.Thank you for such a concise and clear answer.

Comment: Also, I didn't know of the existence of the siunitx package.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is how to get close to what you want using the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xcolor,amsmath}
% Use a dot to separate units:
\sisetup{inter-unit-product = \ensuremath { { } \cdot { } } }  % Taken from siunitx manual page 64
\sisetup{unit-color = red}  % units all in red
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \vec{x}(t) = \left[ \frac{125}{2}\si{(\metre)} 
        + 25(t - \SI{5}{(\second)})\si{(m.s^{-1})} 
        - \frac{5}{2}(t - \SI{5}{(\metre)})^2 \si{(m.s^{-2})}\right]\hat{i},
        \quad\text{si } t\in[5,10]\si{(\second)}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the unit size by default, some would argue that you shouldn't.
It can probably be done by redefining `\si` and `\SI` in a way similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497091/180184).

Notice that in your definition of `\unidm` the main problem you are having is that the `\scriptsize` effects everything in the same group as it, and the group is whatever group you use the command in. This is why enclosing the final argument in `{` and `}` fixes the problem, by doing this you create another group enclosing only the code in your definition.

Another issue with your definition is `\left(\right.`, (try, for example, `\left(\right. \frac{1}{2} \left.\right)`) since there is nothing between matching pairs of delimiters even if the units become large the brackets won't scale with them.
Instead you could use `\left( \mathrm{#1} \right)` and this will still give you upright units but the brackets will scale to match.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
By use of `\medmath` macro defined in the `nccmath` package and if it allowed to use fractions at writing of units, than you can fit your equation in one line.

Another option is to write whole equation in the same font normal size in two lines using `multline` math environment. You may liked this solution.

Both suggestions are the variation of nice @Willoughby answer (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{ {}{\cdot}{} },
         unit-color = red}  % units in red
\begin{document}
\noindent%
With about \qty{20}{\%} smaller font size in the desired part of equation:
    \begin{equation}
\vec{x}(t) = \biggl[ \frac{125}{2}\medmath{\si{(\metre)}
            + 25(t - \qty{5}{(\second)})\si{(m/s)}  
            - \frac{5}{2}(t - \SI{5}{(\metre)})^2 \si{(m/s^{2}})}\biggr]\hat{i},
                \quad\text{si } t\in[5,10]\si{(\second)}
    \end{equation}
or with all equation in normal font size but in two lines:
    \begin{multline}
\vec{x}(t) = \biggl[ \frac{125}{2}\si{(\metre)}
            + 25(t - \SI{5}{(\second)})\si{(m.s^{-1})}  \\
            - \frac{5}{2}(t - \SI{5}{(\metre)})^2 \si{(m.s^{-2})}\biggr]\hat{i},
                \hspace{3em}\text{si } t\in[5,10]\si{(\second)}
    \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]